# Hashset compare 2 string in ArrayList to find code

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains, hashset

Hi I am trying to find a way to compare 2 String codes in a dynamic table that I made here's how I declare it:
this adds students

```
 public void ajouteretudiants(Etudiant unetudiants) throws Exception {

    if (nbreetudiantss >= 30) {
        throw new Exception("Exces d'etudiants");
    } else {
        etudiants.add(unetudiants);
    }
    nbreetudiantss++;
```

this is to get the code of student (first letter of name + first letter of last name + birth year)

```
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}
```

and here's how I try to get it for now:

```
 public String toString() {

    String chaine = "  ";
    for (int i = 0; i < nbreetudiantss; i++) {
        chaine += etudiants.get(i).toString();
    }

    return chaine;

}
```

this is to class name in alphabetical order

```
public String listTriee(){

    // trier le tableau etudiants en ordre alphabetique
    Etudiant temp = null ;
    for (int i=0; i<etudiants.size(); i++){
        for (int j=i+1; j<etudiants.size(); j++)
            if  (etudiants.get(i).getNom().compareTo(etudiants.get(j).getNom()) > 0){
                temp = etudiants.get(j);
                etudiants.set(j,etudiants.get(i));
                etudiants.set(i,temp);
                }
    }
    return toString() ;
    }
```

this is to search if the string we look for is in the table of students(here is my problem)

```
public String rechercher(String code){
    Set<String> monHashSet=new HashSet<String>();
    monHashSet.add(new String(etudiants.get(i).getCode()));

    for (int i=0; i<etudiants.size(); i++){

    }
    return toString() ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Java 8, you can implement something like this

```
Set<String> monHashSet = etudiants.stream()
                .filter(code::equals)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```